# how to get page HTML at client side or javascript

Tags: php, asp.net, javascript

how to get page HTML at client side or through javascript in Asp.net Application. Means if I want to get the html of **http://www.yahoo.com** on client side through javascript or any other

Comment: you can use  iframe method or javascript(ajax) method

Comment: You'll need to add what you want to do with it.  Trivially, the client's browser *has* got the whole page's HTML in order to render it, for example.  It's thus important to note your intended use and environment in order to get an accurate and appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the HTML source of a page on a different hostname from JavaScript, for security reasons (the Same Origin Policy).

So unless you're Yahoo, you would have to run a proxy on the server-side that will fetch http://www.yahoo.com/ and then return its content to the client side via a string in a `<script>` block, or in the response to an XMLHttpRequest (also best JSON-encoded). This is known as a cross-domain proxy.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean get the page html as a string in javascript, you can use:

```
var s = document.body.innerHTML;
```

Though you need to note that this does not give you the html exactly as sent to the browser, it gives you the html constructed from the DOM - essentially meaning any errors will have been fixed, as well as that it will include any dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 1):

link :

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html

there are two ways to create client side includes:

**JavaScript** and **iframe**. Let's look at the advantages and disadvantages of both before we tackle how to do it. 
The JavaScript method is the more seamless of the two. JavaScript code can fetch a fragment of a page from any URL and insert it into another page at any point. The end result looks as good as a server-side include— but only if JavaScript is turned on. And search engines don't see the included text at all, which is a serious problem.

The iframe method is simpler. The iframe element can be used to force a second page to "embed" inside the first page, in much the same way that Flash movies, videos and MP3 players are embedded with the object element. And JavaScript doesn't have to be turned on. But there are disadvantages here too. The iframe element has a fixed width and height, no matter how big the content is. That can mean scrollbars inside your page. And, as of this writing, Google doesn't appear to index the separate page referenced by the iframe so that searchers can find your page.

Answer (score 0):

You use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

I recommend using the [jQuery Ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) javascript library for this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a PHP function similar to `file_get_contents($url)` ?